# MySQL - Add text or texts to a row if conditions are satisfied

Tags: mysql, concatenation, string-concatenation

Sorry if the question is basic, I am learning MySQL.

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
+---+---+-----+
|A  |B  |Con  |
+---+---+-----+
|3  |3  |     |
|2  |3  |     |
|3  |2  |     |
|2  |2  |     |
+---+---+-----+
```

I want to update the `Con` column based on a condition, say add the column name if column is smaller than 3. Instead of writing every condition, I want to add a text to the column with `concat` function, if a condition is satisfied:

```
update table
    set Con = 
        case 
            when A < 3
                then concat(' A ')
            when B < 3 
                then concat(' B ')
        end
```

So, I want something like this:

```
+---+---+-----+
|A  |B  |Con  |
+---+---+-----+
|3  |3  |     |
|2  |3  |A    |
|3  |2  |B    |
|2  |2  |A B  |
+---+---+-----+
```

But, of course this does not work since `case` function is called once and returns only one value. How can I change this code to return all columns (3rd row) if a condition is satisfied for both columns? Thank you.

Comment: Seems to be an SQL variation of [FizzBuzz problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz#Other_uses).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```sql
UPDATE table1
   SET con = CONCAT(CASE WHEN A < 3 THEN ' A ' ELSE '' END, 
                    CASE WHEN B < 3 THEN ' B ' ELSE '' END);
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01664/1)** demo

---

A bit more succinct version that keeps `NULLS` (if you need it)

```sql
UPDATE table1
   SET con = NULLIF(CONCAT(IF(A < 3, ' A ', ''), IF(B < 3, ' B ', '')), '');
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78abc/1)** demo